# Operator linear and continuous on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, bilinear-operator

Let $T:\ell^2\longrightarrow \ell^2$ such that $T(x)= m_kx_k$ with $m \in \ell^\infty$

Proof this operator is linear and continuos and calculate the uniform norm.

Well first show that $T$ is well defined:

$\sum (|m_kx_k|^2)^{1/2} \leq M \|x\|$.

On the other hand $T$ is linear since we have

$T(x+at)=m_k(x_k+ay_k)= m_kx_k+m_ky_k=T(x)+aT(y)$.

For continuity let $\epsilon>0$

$\|T(x)-T(y)\|= \|T(x-y)\|\leq M\|x\|$,taking $\delta=\epsilon/M$ the result is following.

Finally, for the norm if $\|x\|=1$ we have

$\|T(x)\| \leq M$

My problem here is that I can't do the other direction to prove $\|T\|= M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M := \sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |m_k|$ and consider the standard orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\ell^2$. Then
$$\|T(e_k)\| = \|m_ke_k\| = |m_k|\|e_k\| = |m_k|.$$
Taking the supremum yields
$$\|T\| = \sup\limits_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|T(x)\| \geq \sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \|T(e_k)\| = \sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |m_k| = M.$$
Together with $\|T\| \leq M$ you already showed, we get $\|T\| = M$.